# Find $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $\large (\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}-1)^2=49+20\sqrt[3]{6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

find positive intergers $a,b$ such that

$\large (\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}-1)^2=49+20\sqrt[3]{6}$

Here i tried plugging

$x^3=a,y^3=b$

$(x+y-1)^2=x^2+y^2+1+2(xy-x-y)=49+20\sqrt[3]{6} $

the right hand part is a square hence can be written as $(p+q)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if either $a$ or $b$ is a perfect cube, then we have $$ (\sqrt[3]{a}-N)^2 = 49 + 20 \sqrt[3]{6} $$

Convince yourself that the LHS must involve 2 different surd terms, hence this is not possible. Thus, neither $a$ nor $b$ are a perfect cube.

Like you did, expand the terms and consider what they are. Clearly $a, b, a^2, b^2$ are not perfect cubes. If $ab$ is not a perfect cube, then we must have $1 = 49$, which is a contradiction. Hence, we have $ 2\sqrt[3]{ab} + 1 = 49$, or that $ab = 24^3$. We use the substitution $b = \frac{24^3}{a}$ and $x = \sqrt[3]{a}$, and the equation becomes

$$x^2-2x - 48/x + 24^2/x^2 = 20 \sqrt[3]{6}.$$

Multiplying throughout by $x^2$, this equation has real roots of $x = \sqrt[3]{48}$ and $x= \sqrt[3]{288}$, hence $ (a,b) = (48 288) $ and $(288,48)$ are solutions.

Comment: Cool, so (1) $ab$ is a perfect cube although neither $a$ nor $b$ are and (2) substitution trick are the two keys to the solution

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasoning by which you deduce that $ab$ must be a perfect cube?  It seems to rely on the assumption that no linear combination of cube roots of numbers that aren't perfect cubes (i.e. $a$, $b$, $a^2$, $b^2$ and $6$), with rational coefficients, can be a nonzero rational number.  Is that obviously true?

Comment: @BarryCipra Consider the integer (non-surd) parts on both sides. The RHS is 49. For the LHS, the first paragraph shows that $\sqrt[3]{a}+ \sqrt[3]{a^2}+ \sqrt[3]{b}+ \sqrt[3]{b^2}$ must all be surds (non-integers). (Formally, yes you have to show that no non-trivial linear combinations of surds is 0. It's slightly tricky to show, but direct from galois theory.)  If $\sqrt[3]{ab}$ was also a surd, then the only integer part is 1.

Comment: nice solution Calvin Lin.....

Answer (score 1):

I did an Excel search and found $(288,48)=(6^2*2^3,6*2^3)$ and the reverse as solutions.  This is confirmed by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%2acube%20root%286%29%2b2%2acube%20root%2836%29-1%29%5E2)

Answer (score 0):

This one is interesting.

Note that not both $a$ and $b$ are perfect cubes. Why? because otherwise the lhs would be a perfect cube!

Now, let's tackle the case where one of them is a perfect cube, say $a$. In that case, $(\sqrt[3]{a} - 1)$ is an integer. By elementary property of surds, square of this integer must match $49$, integer part of rhs, giving us

$$(\sqrt[3]{a} - 1)^2 = 49$$

And thus, $a = 8^3 = 512$.

The remaining part then reduces to $(7 + \sqrt[3]{b})^2 = 49+20\sqrt[3]{6}$, i.e. $b^{2/3} + 14b^{1/3} = 20(6)^{1/3}$

**Edit:** This quadratic has no integer solution. I was wrong in assuming $6$ as a solution.

This means neither $a$ nor $b$ is a perfect cube

**Edit 2:** I first thought integer solutions must somewhere involve integer cubes. Although neither $a$ nor $b$ are perfect cubes, it turns out that $ab$ is a perfect cube and that is a key to the solution. See Calvin's solution to prove that $ab$ is a perfect cube and find $a$, $b$

Comment: -1 I disagree with $b=6$ being an integer solution to your last equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing a *lot* of arithmetic, here's an "easy" way to solve things:

Note that $(49+20\sqrt[3]{6})^{3/2} = 788.401\ldots$.  Since you're looking for *positive* integer solutions $a$ and $b$, one need *at worst* examine numbers from $1$ to $788$: That is, if $b\ge1$, then $\sqrt[3]{a}\le\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}-1 =(49+20\sqrt[3]{6})^{1/2}$, hence $1\le a\le788$.  In doing so, you will presumably stumble across the solution $(48,288)$ and its reverse, and no others.

You can streamline this a bit by looking for solutions with $a\le b$ so that

$$2\sqrt[3]{a}\le\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b} = 1+(49+20\sqrt[3]{6})^{1/2}=10.238\ldots$$

leads to $a\le134$.  Whether you can easily streamline it further is less clear.